# How do I ensure that a /give command gives to the player who activated it, who may not be the nearest player?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm almost done my map, but I'm having a problem with my `/give` commands.

When you use `@p` to select the nearest player to give items to, it selects the *nearest* player to the command block. The problem is, the nearest player isn't always the *activating* player, i.e., the player that activated the command block.

How can I make sure that the item is given to the person who triggered the command block, who may not always be the nearest player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, you can use tags (I hope you know about tags).

So, you can put a pressure plate and in that command, attach/give the tag to the user in a map.
Then, you can just give it to  `/give @a[tag=<yourtagname>]`

I guessed this helped you.

P.S. I'm new to Minecraft and I have tried it beforehand as I can't trust my logic before testing.

Comment: You can try it as im not like 100% sure i think it works :D

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! It might be helpful to link in some references to wikis, in case people that find this answer don't know how to use tags, etc. It can also be helpful to show a full command, including how to assign tags.

Comment: thanks it worked